# Loading .XML file (.AUX.TIF) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, xml, style-manager

I am working on a project and recently I received a set of files that include a .xml file (.tif.aux), a TIF and a shapefile.

When I open the shape file the color of the blocks is uniform and does not show much information (image 1). I was trying to look for possibilities and a recommendation was to load the .xml file as a style manager in the layer of the shape file, but the error I get is INCORRECT ROOT TAG IN STYLE: PAMDataset (image 2).

I loaded the tif into QGIS and it is well georeferenced, should I try to add the .xml here?

I don't seem to find a way to add it as a style because the type of file does not correspond.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: THIS
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<PAMDataset>
-<PAMRasterBand band="1">
-<Histograms>
-<HistItem>
<HistMin>-0.0351242--</HistMin>

<HistMax>70.2836975--</HistMax>
<BucketCount>1000</BucketCount>
<IncludeOutOfRange>0</IncludeOutOfRange>
<Approximate>1</Approximate>
<HistCounts>10|1|2|4|--|</HistCounts>
</HistItem>

</Histograms>
-<Metadata>
<MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">70.248573303223</MDI>
<MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">32.42327740321</MDI>
<MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>

<MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">10.264988516582</MDI>
</Metadata>
</PAMRasterBand>
</PAMDataset>

Comment: I erased several numbers so it can fit but this is the info I get. It's weird, the person who gave sent me those files says that only with the shape file is enough to get the correct info. But when I add the shape file, I only see everything in one color.

Comment: Thats just some Information about the tiff. You dont need that. You will get the same info when looking at the histogram. About your shapefile: thats normal, you need to symbolize it yourself. E.g. classify it on an attribute it contains.

Comment: Ok... I understand. I checked on Attribute form from the SHPand under Fields I have 
1.2 ID
1.2 MU_ID
1.2 VERSIONID
1.2 RE%P_min
RE%P_max.... And some others. I went to Symbology and I changed Single Symbol for Categorized and created several symbols with different colors and in Value I copied the names of the values I saw in the Atributes form. I applied it and now I don't see anything. I wonder if it's because I have to give it an attribute as you said, A range of numbers or something? If so... where do I find that info and should I add it on legend in each new symbol?

Comment: UPDATE! I found the way. In Symbology I had to change from Single Symbol to Graduated-Select Value- Classify - Apply
Thanks for the help!